# Suitable disposition between QML and C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am constructing a custom UI with Qt 5 an MVC using QML/C++ and I am wondering how to structure the code in regard to what to put in C++ and what to put in QML. The purely visual parts (view) will obviously be put in QML and the data (model) in C++, but what about the parts that aren't that clear? Should I lean towards putting things in C++ and try to reduce the QML code somewhat, or is it better to lean in the other direction, i.e increasing the QML code and reduce the C++ parts? I have not worked enough with Qt/QML to be able to know what is the best way to do this.

Both parts are perfectly feasible imho, but it would take a lot of effort if I need to change this afterwards and therefore I want to get this at least somewhat right before I begin to create a lot of code.

What are your experiences in this when designing QtQuick interfaces? Do you design components mostly in C++ with a thin QML interface on top or the other way around? What are the pros/cons for each solution? What is the preferred way to structure code when designing a UI in QtQuick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my two cents worth. This applies to Qt version 5.1 (ish)

QML was designed to implement the UI. So I've designed those parts that do the visual implementation in QML. Some UI elements can't be done well in Javascript so I do "helpers" or views in C++.

I'm using model/view for data display. All the models are implemented in C++ (I used sqlite databases for my last application).

QML is still a work in progress so if you stray too far from standard telephone interfaces there isn't much implemented. The standards for UI behavior you expect from desktops aren't present at all.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking somewhat along these lines too. For simple models just to present something static (e.g. a static list or something) I tend to put them too in QML, but for more complex stuff it is definitely done in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally make your models and controllers in c++. Use QML for the view.
Inside the QML view you can rather easily incorporate components written in C++ (there is a plug-in system and an API for visual and non-visual C++ components to integrate well within QML)

QML performance has improved a lot in Qt 5.1+ with regards to UI rendering, but you should limit the amount of logic you do in javascript (inside qml).

What QML excels at is declaring what the UI looks like and how it should be connected to signal and slots of the controller, if you end up writing convoluted logic inside your qml files, you are probably doing something wrong.

PS: there are several big open-source project that use QML, you can find them on github. You could use them as style guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, aligns well with how I think, a lot of qml logic is not something to strive for and should better be put in C++. Thanks about the tip to look at the open source projects.